# getting "[Connect-MsolService], HttpRequestException" with a service account

Tags: powershell

I have an issue when connecting to MSonline using a service account to run scheduled tasks

When running the following lines under my admin account, it connects fine but if I run it under a service account (srv_scheduler), it fails

```
#Load MSOL  Module
Import-Module -Name  MSOnline

# Define variables.
$usr = "srv_m365_read@xxxxxx.com"
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential $usr,$pwd

#Load MSOL  Module
Connect-MsolService -cred $cred


Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService -cred $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

The service account has MFA disabled. What am I missing ?

Thanks.
Gaetan

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to change the variable name `$pwd`, because in PowerShell this is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the error changing $pwd to $pass

Comment: Did you configure the scheduled task to "Run with highest privileges" ? and does your user `srv_scheduler` have the "Log on as a batch job" permission?

Comment: Yes. All the tasks are running with "Run with highest privileges" and I've added the account to log on as a batch job as the same account is pulling reports for AD and VMware.

The above lines are actually run when invoking a powershell session as srv_scheduler as well to narrow it down

Comment: Still no luck. I have to use my admin account in the meantime which is not ideal